# What the replacement for GoToStateAction in SL 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I try to migrate a SL 4 app to SL5 and got following error when compiling the app:

```
Error   17  The tag 'GoToStateAction' does not exist in XML namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions'.    

Error   31  The type 'GoToStateAction' from assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Interactions' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Silverlight 5 project.
```

the xaml for this error is:
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="ShowStatus"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="HideStatus"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: install Blend Preview for SL5. Thanks.